# How to access angular md-tab elements from protractor?

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

Html:

```
<md-tab-group class="my-tab-group">
    <md-tab class="my-tab"></md-tab>
    <md-tab class="my-tab"></md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

e2e test:

```
elems = element(by.css('.my-tab-group')).all(by.css('.my-tab'))
expect(elems).toBeTruthy();
expect(elems.count()).toEqual(2);
```

This test is failing: `Expected 0 to equal 2`.

Why protractor is not able to identify the number of tabs. This is happening due to angular element `md-tab-group`. If I comment `md-tab-group`, I am able to access tabs. How to access the tab elements when `md-tab-group` is present?

P.S. I am using Angular 4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular create new elements for md-tab (angular directive). Such tabs can be referred by ids such as "md-tab-label-0-0" for 1st tab, "md-tab-label-0-1" for 2nd tab, as shown in following image.

[image]

1st tab element can be accessed by

```
element(by.id('md-tab-label-0-0'));
```

And, answer to the question would be

```
elems = element.all(by.css('.mat-tab-labels'))
expect(elems).toBeTruthy();
expect(elems.count()).toEqual(2);
```

Comment: In some random cases, the id becomes md-tab-label-1-0 instead of md-tab-label-0-0, and md-tab-label-1-1 instead of md-tab-label-0-1, is there a pattern for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this then in order to retrieve the mength

```
elems = element(by.css('.my-tab-group')).all(by.css('.my-tab'));
elems.then(function (result) {
  expect(result.length).toEqual(2);
});
```

Or

```
elems.count().then(function (size) {
   expect(size).toEqual(2);
});
```

Comment: No, its not working. " expect(elems.count()).toEqual(2)" is correct. The problem is with "md-tab-group". Protractor is not identifying elements inside "md-tab-group".